# Swift - Grand Central Dispatch vs Blocks/Closures

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to write an HTTP request using Swift and I really only see people going one way or another (actually not so much GCD) to do HTTP requests on iOS.

**If I want to make an HTTP request in iOS, what would be the best way to go about it: Use Grand Central Dispatch or write some closure block?** Also, where can I find some great examples. From what I read online, I'm having a hard time seeing the benefits of one over the other.

At the moment, I have this code:

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), { ()->() in

        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.authenticateUser()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    })
```

From what I see in the Debug Session tab for the Processor, I can see it jump from Thread X to Thread Y (for authenticateUser) and back to Thread X. Which is good - this is what I want (I'm sure).

Any good examples of GCD or Blocks/Closures written in Swift that you might be aware of would be very handy too. Thanks!

Comment: GCD uses closures.  You can't use GCD in Swift without using closures.  Anyway, have you looked at the [*URL Loading System Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)?

Comment: Take a look: https://medium.com/swift-programming/http-in-swift-693b3a7bf086.

Comment: @MaximShoustin is this better than using GCD or a more "Correct Way" of doing async http requests?

Comment: Using blocks + dispatch_async VS. NSURLSession: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/using-blocks-dispatchasync-vs-nsurlsession. For ios7+ i would use NSURLSession. For backwards compatibility - GCD

Answer (score 3):

Use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html) to make your HTTP request. Use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) to implement concurrency in your app (multiple things happening at the same time). And use [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to give a structure to your application. As you can see now, all of them can be used at the same time.

By the way, always remember this: All UI modifications must be called in the main thread, in your code you are calling this `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` on a concurrent queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSURLSession. Basic usage is like

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, urlResponse, error in
    // handle the response
}.resume()
```

Comment: This actually handles the request in a new thread? If so, do I place the completion code inside the braces where you say ' // handle the response '?

Comment: it asynchronously makes http request and then calls closure (handle the response part) on main thread.

Comment: is this better than using the GCD code I have in my question up above? If so, why?

Comment: "A new thread" is not your problem. Don't worry about threads in Cocoa. Worry about whether it's asynchronous. `NSURLSession` is async, and is the tool you generally want to use for this. The OS will manage the details for you.